# Story about a man who creates a virus which implants his cloned child in millions of women

Tags: story-identification

A scientist creates a virus (bacteria?) which, when encountering a woman, implants a fetal clone of him, which the woman is pregnant with.  Millions of his clones have already been born, and society is having a hard time accommodating them.

The man is in hiding, working as a teacher in a special class for his clones.  He is evaluating one particular young clone, who apparently suffered from fetal alcohol syndrome, which was detected based on his unexpectedly low test scores.

It's a short story, read in the 2000s or earlier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is  [*The Cuckoo's Boy*](http://www.robertreedwriter.com/novels/cuckoosboys.html) by Robert Reed.

> In the near-future title story, a lonely genius clones himself -- not
>   once, but millions of times -- by creating a virus that affects
>   pregnant women. Throughout the world, women give birth to baby boys
>   with the genetics of Phillip Stevens. Then a few years later, a man
>   with a mysterious past becomes a mentor to three of these clones --
>   and as their teacher, he tests and challenges them. Are these boys
>   little more than genetic copies of Stevens? Or are they distinct
>   individuals, with unique personalities and coming-of-age problems?

Comment: Isfdb link: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?82591